# Thread safe iterating over LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have a private LinkedHashMap which is used for reading (only for reading) from different threads:

```
class foo {

  private LinkedHashMap map = ...;


  public publicMethodCalledFromDifferentThreads() {

     for (Object foo : map) {
        ...
     }
  }
}
```

This implementation is not thread safe and so the `for` loop can't behave correctly. I tried to find a solution by myself and the only thing I came up with is the following:

```
class foo {

  private LinkedHashMap map = ...;
  private Map.Entry[] mapEntries = map.entrySet().toArray() ...;

  public publicMethodCalledFromDifferentThreads() {

     for (int i = 0; i < mapEntries.length; i++) {
        mapEntries[i]...
        ...
     }
  }
}
```

So in the end I need to have two variables and the iteration gets really complex. What would be the nicest way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: if you're really only reading from it (never modifying it while it's being read), then afaik, it doesn't need to be threadsafe. What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: My problem is that once there are two threads iterating over the map, the iterator jumps randomly from entry to entry. I thought that this is caused by the shared iterator, are you saying that it can'T be the case?

Comment: @Vojtěch Without modifications to the LinkedHashMap itself, it does not appear that, at least in the Sun Version, the iterators can conflict: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java#LinkedHashMap.LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry%28%29 (Is it absolutely guaranteed that the object is not being mutated in any way?) The important traversal is standard: `nextEntry = e.after;` (where `nextEntry` is a member in the new iterator), which performs no side-effects otherwise.

Comment: Okay, you are right, the problem was elsewhere, thanks for pointing me in other direction!

Comment: @Vojtěch What was the problem?

Comment: There was some other variable which was being overwritten and it seemed it was a problem with the iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only reading, and the underlying objects are not being modified, both the list and the things in the list, there should be no threading issue.

What issue are you actually experiencing?

I think it's possible you are modifying your LinkedHashMap somehow.

More over, how are you determining the threads are jumping around?  Are you sure you are not just seeing output from the 2 threads intermixed, which would look like jumping around, even though each thread is iterating sequentially? For example if each thread printed its current entry you might see something like

123 12 45 345 6....

which is sequential....

Comment: @hvgotcodes, The documentation you quote is only relevant for **access-ordered** linked hash maps, which has to be explicitly stated when constructing the map. The default is insertion-ordered, where calling `get` is not a structural modification. Given the symptoms, this seems like the case, but I figured I would point out the distinction.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, you've shown me to look for the problem somewhere else and it helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [synchronized map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29).

```
private final Map<K, V> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<K, V>());

public void foo() {
    synchronized(map) {
        for(K key : map.keySet()) {
            // thread safe iteration
        }
    }
}
```